# How to make a z-depth buffer with pygame?

Tags: 3d, python, pygame

I am making a 3d renderer with python and so far am sorting the triangles which I want to replace with a z-depth buffer. The thing is, I don't know how to make a z-depth buffer in pygame. I still want it to be playable however.

By the way, I am using pygame polygons.

Comment: [This answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/125436/40264) appears to describe what you're looking for.

Comment: Hello & welcome to the Game Dev SE! We also have [this post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/129552/33287) discussing some potential issues with implementing a homemade z-depth buffer with SDL2. However, I'm not familiar enough with Pygame or your project to know how applicable the details are to your situation. Could you edit your question to include more information about the problems you are having & why you are considering using a depth buffer? It's possible that there may be some other solutions.

Comment: But I don't want to loop through each pixel. It would be super slow.

Comment: Pygame is made with sdl so It shouldn't be to different

Comment: Looks like you want to use a depth buffer to fix issues that arise even with sorting triangles. Depth buffers work on pixels, unfortunately. [This other question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/183833/how-to-sort-polygons-without-a-depth-buffer) could be of use.